# I need to know how many pounds of force a 3 million pound object has moving at 1 mph

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, momentum

How many pounds of force does a 3 million pound object have moving at 0.1, 0.5, and 1 mph?

Comment: Your words *"How many pounds of force does a [...] object have [while moving]?"* expresses a fundamental misunderstanding about the nature of force (as the word is used in physics) that I've seen from students many times. It is possible that the concept you are looking for is "momentum".

Answer (score 1):

Force is the rate of change of momentum, or alternatively mass times acceleration. So an object moving at a constant speed isn't experiencing any force. We only get a force when we try and slow the object down or speed it up.

So as it stands your question can't be answered - or the answer is *zero*, which I doubt is very helpful. I'm guessing you're really thinking about how much force the object generates when it hits something, but for that we need to know how rapidly the object comes to a halt. The force is going to be a lot greater if it hits a brick wall than if it hits a giant marshmallow.

If you want to work this out for yourself, then if $m$ is the mass of the object and $v$ is its velocity, and it comes to a halt in a time $t$ then the force is:

$$ F = \frac{mv}{t} $$

But you'll need to careful about units. I strongly recommend you convert the mass to kilograms and the velocity to metres per second. Then if you measure the time in seconds the force will come out in Newtons. If you want to convert back to units of pound force one Newton is about 0.225 lbf.